# How to run nunit tests with asp.net 5 projects, especially with ReSharper?

Tags: nunit, resharper, asp.net-core

I am developing an asp.net 5 application targeting dnx451.

The asp.net 5 project relies some libraries with unit-tests written for nunit 2.x. So the reasonable choice for me is to use nunit for testing the asp.net 5 project.

When I running the unit test in ReSharper, the ReSharper says "Test not run" with additional message "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly xxx ".

Both nunit 2.6.4 and 3.0.0-beta-2 results the same error.

Any one has successfully running nunit tests against an dnx project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run xUnit 2.1.0-beta-\* for DNX projects with ReSharper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827067/how-to-run-xunit-2-1-0-beta-for-dnx-projects-with-resharper)

Comment: It is not a duplication~~~ this is for xUnit, the other is for NUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNX tests aren't currently supported by ReSharper. It's a whole new execution model, and hasn't yet been implemented for ReSharper. I'd expect to see support as DNX and asp.net stabilise and near release. Also, I don't believe nunit itself supports running as a DNX test runner - the xunit team have a separate project to plug into DNX: https://github.com/xunit/dnx.xunit

Comment: What's even worse is that if you enable build output generation for the project (the automatic NuGet packaging part), the actual assemblies are *almost* where ReSharper expects them - just one folder away.

Comment: hey matt - any update on this? https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/575 has been completed so i'm wondering about the resharper support of it

Comment: I'm working on it right now! ReSharper will have support for running DNX tests. Right now, the plan is for only xunit tests to be discovered and run - mstest or nunit tests will be ignored (not even discovered in the editor, because we can't run them). The way I read that nunit issue is that it can run under CoreCLR/DNX, but isn't a DNX runner per se, like the xunit runner. As I understand it, nunit still has to implement the DNX runner integration. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

NUnit does not support the DNX core.

Follow this issue to see when nunit adds dnx support.  https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/575

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NUnit has (partial) support as of v3.0.0-RC
http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, by saying "Especially with ReSharper", you mean that you want to know how to run NUnit tests, and if possible, with ReSharper.  That being said, here's how to run NUnit tests against ASP.NET Core (Formerly known as ASP.NET 5) in Visual Studio without needing ReSharper:

1. Add a new project and choose *Console Application (.NET Core)*.  Trying to use class libraries will currently report an error.
2. Add the latest version of the *dotnet-test-nunit* NuGet package (Make sure that *Include prerelease* is checked, or you won't find it in the NuGet feed)
3. Add the latest version of the *NUnit* NuGet package.
4. Edit *project.json* and add this line: `"testRunner": "nunit",`

Now you can run your tests by choosing *Test - Run - All Tests* from the Visual Studio menu.

Your *project.json* file should look like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-1",
    "ProjectUnderTest": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "NUnit": "3.4.1"
  },
  "testRunner": "nunit",

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```