# NUnit 3 / Resharper 10.0.2 / Visual Studio 2015 / Asp.Net5 Project Test will not run

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nunit-3.0, resharper-10.0

I've created a Unit Test Project in Asp.Net5 with a standard Class Library Package.  I'm using NUnit 3 with Resharper 10.0.2 and when I run the unit test I get the following error.[image]

The following are my references

[image]

Here is the output of the test runner post error
[image]

Am I missing something here???  When I take the file and create a aspnet4 project template and add the Nunit3 references the test run fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post dated Jun 14,2015 [How to run nunit tests with asp.net 5 projects, espically with ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826762/how-to-run-nunit-tests-with-asp-net-5-projects-espically-with-resharper)  that seems to indicate that the Test Runner does not support DNX test with NUnit and while I can add references to Nunit to aspnet5 projects and compile the test fail to run because of incompatibility.  Given the date of this post I wasn't sure if this was still the case as I'm finding many articles more than 4-5 months old are already out of date.  If anyone has found a way to get resharper to run Nunit test in an ASP.NET5 Project template please let me know.

Comment: according to https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/575 it should be possible. did you manage to find a way yet?

Comment: no, we decided not to use the aspnet 5 project structures as of yet because of them still being in development